# Erro ao gerar o relatório: <Coluna> e <Coluna> têm propriedades conflitantes: propriedade DataType incompatível

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, datatable

Ao tentar preencher um datatable dinamicamente ocorre o erro na hora de realizar um merge dos demais dados.

```
            For Each drw In dtbTemp.Rows
                dtb = obj.Enquadra(drw.Item("IDCON_TMP"), drw.Item("IDCAR_TMP"))
                dtb.Columns.Add("IDCON_CON", GetType(Integer))
                For Each drwTit In dtb.Rows
                    drwTit.Item("IDCON_CON") = drw.Item("IDCON_TMP")
                Next
                dtb.TableName = "Titulo"
                If dst.Tables.IndexOf(dtb.TableName) > -1 Then
                    dst.Merge(dtb)
                Else
                    dst.Tables.Add(dtb)
                End If
                dtb = New DataTable
            Next
```

O seguinte erro é lançado:

```
Erro ao gerar o relatório: <Coluna> e <Coluna> têm propriedades conflitantes: propriedade DataType incompatível.
```

Estou pegando todos os registros do dataTable temporário e tratando cada linha e inserindo em novo dataTable.

Answer (score 0):

Use o MissingSchemaAction.Ignore como parâmetro no Merge do DataSet. Esse parâmetro especifica a ação a ser tomada quando adicionar dados ao DataSet e os DataTable ou DataColumn está ausente. O **Ignore** ignora as colunas extras ou em conflito.

O trecho do código deve ficar assim:

```
dst.Merge(dtb, True, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)
```

O true é para preservar as mudanças no DataTable.

Fonte: Documentação no msdn.